# Is a horizontal line an increasing or decreasing function?

Tags: functions

This is the definition of an increasing and decreasing function.

"A function $f(x)$ increases on an interval I if $f(b)≥f(a)\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $f(b)>f(a) \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly increasing.

Conversely, A function $f(x)$ decreases on an interval I if $f(b)≤f(a)\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $f(b)<f(a) \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly decreasing.

Then how would a horizontal line be described? If $f(x_2)=f(x_1)\;\; \forall x_2>x_1$ does that mean that a horizontal line meets the definition of an increasing function and a decreasing function?

Comment: this means the function is *constant*

Comment: Yes, a constant function is both increasing and decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means it is neither strictly increasing nor strictly decreasing, *it is a constant function*.

However, the way you have defined increasing and decreasing functions, the given horizontal line satisfies both definitions.

But it is better to avoid putting this type of function in any such class. It should be rightly referred to as a **constant function**.

Comment: Of course it is a constant function. But on his definitions (which are fairly standard) it is also both an increasing function and a decreasing function, but neither a strictly increasing function nor a strictly decreasing function.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Downvotes??

Comment: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Why down votes!? Please have a kind discussion instead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an horizontal line is a function $f$ such that $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and, if $a\leq b\to f(a)=c\leq c =f(b)$. Idem for $\geq$

Answer (score 0):

Inject $f(x)=c$ in the definitions:

"A function $c$ increases on an interval I if $c≥c\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $c>c \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly increasing.

Conversely, A function $c$ decreases on an interval I if $c≤c\;\;\forall b>a$, where $a,b \in I$. If $c<c \;\;\forall \;\;b>a$, the function is said to be strictly decreasing."

You should be able to see for yourself what property holds.